# $scope.item in directive is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with my directive and controller. The variable item in scope is undefined in directive, even though I passed it in html. This is my code:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/main.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl" 
        });
}]);
```

controller.js:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.item = "x";
});
```

directive.js:

```
app.directive("exampleDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
           item: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "views/item.html"
    };
});
```

index.html:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

main.html:

```
<div example-directive item="item"></div>
```

item.html:

```
<div>{{ item }}</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my code to:

```
app.directive("exampleDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: "views/item.html"
    };
});
```

and now there is "x" in scope.$parent.item. But why it isn't present inside directive?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: I "minimized" your code for JSFiddle and it's working for me  http://jsfiddle.net/2EVkP/

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems to work just fine with latest Angular stable http://plnkr.co/edit/6oXDIF6P04FXZB335voR?p=preview maybe you are trying to use `templateUrl` thats pointing to somewhere it doesn't exist.

Another thing, use primitives only when strictly needed. In case you ever need to modify value of `item`, you won't be able to do so since you are using a primitive. Plus, if you need "more info" to go inside your isolated scopes, and to avoid attribute soup (`attr-this="that"`, `attr-that="boop"`, `my-otherstuff="anotheritem.member"`, etc) you can pass the two-way bind of an object that handle more data.

Or if you need to share state through multiple controllers, directives, etc, use a service instead and use dependency injection, and there's no need to pass in objects/primitives to your isolated scope, and you can assure state, and that's best practice "the Angular way".

Comment: templateUrl exists. In fact I have a service that returns data and assigns it to a scope and it is available in directive. But if I assign something in controller to scope, such as $scope.item = "x", then scope.item in directive returns undefined.

Comment: then it's a problem with using a primitive like I said, and you need to call `$scope.$apply` or `$timeout` whenever you change your values from "out sources", such as http calls, jquery element events, vanilla javascript code, etc. could you post more of your code, so it resembles more of your code? that way I can update the plunkr with the real use case

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2844/ which is essentially the same thing just without the route information.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive("exampleDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
           item: "="
        },
        template: "<div>{{ item }}</div>"
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.item = 'Superhero';
}
```

With the view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div example-directive item="item"></div>
</div>
```

This leads me to believe it could be a scope issue. So try encapsulating the controller scope variable in a container:

```
$scope.cont = { item: 'x' };
```

And in the view

```
<div example-directive item="cont.item"></div>
```